# wampserver does not work after creating virtual host

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

When we create virtual host on WAMP server, did we need to uncomment these lines or not:

```
# Virtual hosts 
# Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

because when I uncomment these lines from `httpd.conf` apache file, WAMP turns to yellow (not working).

I also made a change to `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. I removed dummy data and used:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 project1 
::1 localhost
::1 project1
```

project1 is project name located at `c:/wamp/www/` directory. Only these lines exist in file after editing.

I edited this WAMP file `\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

I removed previous dummy data create virtual host and in windows file
like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/project1"
    ServerName project1
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/project1">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried other answers on SO with no luck.

Comment: When you say "does not work", what specifically is or is not happening that tells you its not working? Are you getting any errors on the server?

Comment: after all this process i restart Apache services then WAMPSERVER turns to yellow and i cant open Localhost, when i click on Localhost it comes like Unable to open

Comment: Look at the apache error log and if there is nothing in there look at the windows event viewer for error messages from Apache

Comment: And if that solved your problem, post your own answer otherwise this question is of no use to others.

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/project1"
    ServerName project1 
</VirtualHost>
Untill here WAMP SERVER is green localhost is opening 
when i click on project name its again open normal localhost page thats the only issue But 
Most important when i make change Apache file httpd.conf I just uncomment the virtual host and Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf 
After that Apache services are not starting WAMP is yellow

Comment: i am new here i try to write properly but its mixed everything i apologize

Comment: Problem Solved , I just uncomment this line # Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf  in Apache file httpd.conf now its working fine.

Comment: I need help here please page redirect not working dummy code is here when i submit form its shows redirected page SOURCECODE and page stay on same page                                                                                     if($num_row==1){    
 $home="http://dummy/";
  $_SESSION['user_id']=$row['id'];
  header("Location:".$home); 
  exit;
 }else{
 //echo 'Incorrect Email And Password';
 }